# How to extract all href from a class in Python Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, iframe, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to extract people's href from the URL https://www.dx3canada.com/agenda/speakers.

I tried:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.display-flex card vancouver')
href_output = []
for ele in elems:
    href_output.append(ele.get_attribute("href"))
print(href_output)
```

But the output list returns nothing...

The expected href shown as the image below and I hope the outputs as a list of hrefs:
[image]

I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To extract the people's **href** attribute from the URL https://www.dx3canada.com/agenda/speakers as the the desired elements are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the *visibility of all elements located*.
- You can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.dx3canada.com/agenda/speakers')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#whovaIframeSpeaker")))
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.display-flex.card.vancouver")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9942778/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907682/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907688/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907676/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907696/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907690/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907670/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907693/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9942779/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9908087/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907671/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907681/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907673/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907678/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907689/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907674/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907684/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907685/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907686/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9942780/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907695/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907687/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907683/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907692/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907672/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907697/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907680/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907679/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907675/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907677/', 'https://whova.com/embedded/speaker_detail/dcrma_202003/9907694/']
  ```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Great answer -- Could you explain the use of `add_experimental_option` for `enable-automation` and `useAutomationExtension`? I have never seen these options before and I am curious to know what they are used for!

Comment: @Christine In short, the two `experimental_option()` **enable-automation** and **useAutomationExtension** I'm using for a few different things, two examples are, to get rid of the inforbars, not to get detected as a bot and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Your images are in an `iframe`, so you will need to switch to this before you can scrape the `href` attributes using `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`.

Then, to get the list of all `href` attributes, you may need to run some Javascript to scroll the image into view, and handle the case where the images may be lazy loading the `href`:

```
# first, switch to iframe
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='whovaIframeSpeaker']")))

elements_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'template-section-body')]/a[contains(@class, 'display-flex card vancouver')]")

for element in elements_list:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
    print(element.get_attribute("href"))
```

The results of this code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Christine. I tried the code above but doesn't work. https://www.dx3canada.com/agenda/speakers is the link I am scraping

Comment: @Bangbangbang  After looking at your web page, I see the problem is an `iframe` now. I have updated my answer and tested it. The `href` are all successfully printing now.

Answer (score 0):

For your css selector use .display-flex.card.vancouver instead.

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.display-flex.card.vancouver')
```

Each word is a class, so you need to place a dot in the front of each one.

Comment: hmm. I added the dots but still get nothing.