# Selenium - How to send keys within an iFrame?

Tags: selenium, iframe, webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I'm coding a selenium automated bot, and I want to send keys to a input that I got from iFrame, check the code line:

```
username = bot.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='Registration form' and @class='top']")
```

Can you guys help me? I can click on the input, but, on send the keys, it doesn't work and deselect the input field.

Comment: If the input element present inside an iframe then You need to switch to `iframe` before interacting with input element.Please [edit] your question with relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't send *character sequence* to the `<iframe>` element rather you would send *character sequence* to the `<input>` element within the `<iframe>`. As the the desired element is within a `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='Registration form' and @class='top']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@attribure_name='attribute_value']"))).send_keys("Igor Duca")
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.t-online.de/themen/e-mail')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.top[title='Registration form']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[attribure_name='attribute_value']"))).send_keys("Igor Duca")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [How to extract all href from a class in Python Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59145944/how-to-extract-all-href-from-a-class-in-python-selenium/59146082#59146082)

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)