# How to click on every title within the page to scrape the title

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait

For example this is the main page link
https://www.nationalhardwareshow.com/en-us/attend/exhibitor-list.html
go to these page then `click` on first title like these `10X Innovations - Swift ULV`and then get the `title`

[image]

This is code

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver =webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://www.nationalhardwareshow.com/en-us/attend/exhibitor-list.html')
data = []
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
hrefs = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='text-center-mobile wrap-word']//ancestor::a[1]")))[:5]]
windows_before  = driver.current_window_handle
for href in hrefs:
  driver.execute_script("window.open('" + href +"');")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
  windows_after = driver.window_handles
  new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0]
  driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
  data.append(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1[@class='wrap-word']"))).text)
  driver.close()
  driver.switch_to.window(windows_before)
print(data)
```

Comment: What is your problem/question?

Comment: My problem is that when I click on every title and then go inside the page and then scrape title and they will give me the `Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document`

Comment: on which line exactly you get the exception?

Comment: these line   `vid = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'company-info']//h3)]")`

Answer (score 0):

Your current problem is invalid XPath `//div[contains(@class,'company-info']//h3)]` - wrong parentheses usage. You need to use `//div[contains(@class,'company-info')]//h3` instead.

However, if you want to scrape data from each company entry on page then your clicking links approach is not good.

Try to implement the following:

- get `href` attribute of every link. Since not all links initially displayed on page you need to trigger all possible XHRs, so create `count` variable to get current links count and do in while loop:

  - execute send `END` hardkey to scroll page down
  - try to wait until current links count > `count`. If True - re-define `count` with new value. If Exception - break the loop (there are no more links remain to load)
  - get `href` of all link nodes `//div[@class="company-info"]//a`
- in `for` loop navigate to each link with `driver.get(<URL>)`
- scrape data

Answer (score 0):

With in the [2022 EXHIBITOR LIST](https://www.nationalhardwareshow.com/en-us/attend/exhibitor-list.html) webpage to [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on each link to scrape you can collect the [***href***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59146082/7429447) attributes and open them in the [adjascent tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51893230/7429447) as follows:

- Code Block (sample for first 5 entries):

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.nationalhardwareshow.com/en-us/attend/exhibitor-list.html')
  data = []
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  hrefs = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='text-center-mobile wrap-word']//ancestor::a[1]")))[:5]]
  windows_before  = driver.current_window_handle
  for href in hrefs:
    driver.execute_script("window.open('" + href +"');")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
    windows_after = driver.window_handles
    new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0]
    driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
    data.append(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1[@class='wrap-word']"))).text)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(windows_before)
  print(data)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['10X Innovations - Swift ULV', '21st Century Inc', '3V Snap Ring LLC.', 'A-ipower Corp', 'A.A.C. Forearm Forklift Inc']
  ```

Comment: ` raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)` they give these error

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: again give  the error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\CaptainCazRepo\src\up.py", line 16, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
  File "E:\python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: `

Comment: @AmenAziz Use the full code, not partial code. The new page will open in the adjascent tab.

Comment: I have edit the code as you share  check it

Comment: I've increased the wait time, can you please update accordingly and update me the result?

Comment: they give me again error I am not understanding why they gave me error and they gave me error again and again on these line 
    `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))`

Comment: But, does the link opens in the adjascent tab?

Comment: yes the link will be open in adajscent tab

Comment: Are there any extra tabs opened by the webdriver? Can you update `WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))`

Comment: yes have any desk softaware I will  share my screen

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: ok let discuss in room